# Combine multiple for loops to remove classes on click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for some advice regarding having 2-3 for loops in one javascript statement to find elements with a particular class then add and remove classes. I'm fairly new to javascript so bear with me.

What I have so far works but I just don't want to get into bad habits down the line. As an example I have a navigation link that has a class of to--kenya, there is also another element with the same class and when either of these 2 elements are clicked i want the same thing to happen which will be to add an active--section class to the associated section named kenya.

The first for loop will look for all the elements with the class name to--kenya and add a click listener to them. If neither of these 2 elements has the class active--section it then runs another for loop looking for all the sections that have a class called active--section and removes it if it has the class. Then a third for loop runs checking all the navigation links to find a link with the active--link class then removes it if it has it. Once this is complete i just add a class to my new active navigation link as well as add the active--section class to the now active section.

Hope this makes sense, I'm just looking for the cleanest way of doing this.

```
 <main class="main__wrapper">

  <nav class="navigation">
    <div class="navigation__inner">
      <div class="navigation__logo">
        <a href="#" class="navigation__logo--text">Safari</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="navigation__destinations">
        <li class="navigation__destinations--item">
          <a href="#" class="navigation__link to--home active--link">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation__destinations--item">
          <a href="#" class="navigation__link navigation__link--kenya to--kenya">Kenya</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation__destinations--item">
          <a href="#" class="navigation__link to--botswana">Botswana</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation__destinations--item">
          <a href="#" class="navigation__link to--south-africa">South Africa</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation__destinations--item">
          <a href="#" class="navigation__link to--zambia"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navigation__list">
        <li class="navigation__item">
          <a href="#" class="navigation__link to--contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

<div class="up__next">
      <div class="up__next__box up__next--kenya to--kenya up__next__box--active">
        <div class="up__next__content">
          <div class="up__next__info">
            <h4 class="up__next__heading">Next</h4>
            <span class="up__next__text">Kenya - Maasai Mara National Reserve</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="up__next__img">
          <div class="up__next__img--kenya"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

  <section class="home sections active--section">
    <div class="home__info__box">
      <h2 class="heading__primary home__heading--primary">Heading</h2>
      <span class="home__info__box--text">text</span>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="kenya sections">
    <div class="kenya__info__box">
      <h2 class="heading__primary kenya__heading--primary">Masai Mara</h2>
      <span class="kenya__info__box--text">text</span>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>


//Global variables

var sections = document.querySelectorAll('.sections');
var navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__link');
var navHome = document.querySelector('.navigation__link--home');
var navKenya = document.querySelector('.navigation__link--kenya');
var home = document.querySelector('.home');
var kenya = document.querySelector('.kenya');
var toKenya = document.querySelectorAll('.to--kenya');
var upNextKenya = document.querySelector('.up__next--kenya');


//Event listeners

for (var i = 0; i < toKenya.length; i++) {
    toKenya[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (!kenya.classList.contains('active--section')) {
            for (var s = 0; s < sections.length; s++) {
                sections[s].classList.remove('active--section');
            }
            for (var l = 0; l < navLink.length; l++) {
                navLink[l].classList.remove('active--link');
            }
            kenya.classList.add('active--section');
            navKenya.classList.add('active--link');
            upNextKenya.classList.remove('up__next__box--active');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This question should be moved to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: no need to loop all elements with nested loops just use jquery selector  then add your css class 
      $('.navigation__link to--home').addClass('Active')
jquery selector will solve your issue

Comment: @Hisham No jQuery tag in OP question, so not an option

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech Might want to take a look at [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253975)...